# Xamarin Forms resizing a scrollview and image within a grid

Tags: c#, gridview, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I have a grid with 2 rows both 50% height of the screen.
The top row contains an image, the bottom a scrollview.
What I would like to achieve is when I start to scroll, the image reduces in height to 25% of the screen and the scrollview to 75%.

I did this by resizing the row heights on the scrollview.Scrolled but it seems a bit 'jumpy' as the code is called several times per scroll.  I also tried to TranslateTo, this looked better as it was animated, but it left me with a blank space under the scrollview.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: could you show your code ?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/xamarinium/ParallaxScroll